# Editing undeleted answer on the cusp of 5 minutes creates new answer

Tags: bug, edits, answers

Something strange just happened. I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716064/finding-all-values), then deleted the answer, then undeleted and edited it. The timestamp was 4 minutes. I highlighted a portion of a text that I wanted to erase, and pressed the backspace button. The screen jumped strangely, and the words were still there. I erased them again, typed a correction, and saved my edit.

Then I saw that there now appeared a second answer of mine there. But I edited, as far as I could tell. There were no usual warnings about adding second answer.

So I deleted the first answer (which stayed in its unedited version). Seems like a bug.

***UPDATE:*** not a bug, as explained in the comments.

Comment: Your browser interpreted the backspace, not the editor. You went back in your history and you were back on the form for new answers.

Comment: E.g. this is driver error, not a bug.

Comment: in that case I would have gotten the warning about adding second answer. I didn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters moreover, I still had the edit window, filled with my old text. I didn't type it all again.

Comment: Yes, your browser remembered what you filled in when you posted there, that's normal behaviour. You don't get a warning because that warning is only shown when opening a page where you already posted (so loading from the web, not from history). Your historical page didn't have your posted answer on it.

Comment: I can readily reproduce this any time I just posted an answer somewhere. Just hit backspace *after clicking outside the editor*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yes, I posted this by using the backspace button!*

You didn't hit a bug. You accidentally told your browser to go back a page in your browser history.

When your focus is *outside* the editor, the <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> key is a short-cut for going back in your browser history. Your browser then shows you the original *Post Your Answer* form, not the *Save Edits* form! Your browser usually shows you what you entered into that form just before posting, so this can look like you are editing your existing post.

Hitting the *Post Your Answer* button then actually posts a new answer.

I usually recognise this because I am looking at an old revision (I edit my posts a lot), but you can also look at the title and buttons:

> [image: posting instead of editing]

Comment: great explanation! thanks. :) now about them elections... have more votes to cast...

Answer (score 2):

*This was my original answer, I then used backspace to go back in my browser history to post the other answer*.

You didn't hit a bug. You accidentally told your browser to go back a page in your browser history.

When your focus is *outside* the editor, the <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> key is a short-cut for going back in your browser history. Your browser then shows you the original *Post Your Answer* form, not the *Save Edits* form! Your browser usually shows you what you entered into that form just before posting, so this can look like you are editing your existing post.

Hitting the *Post Your Answer* button then actually posts a new answer.

When editing, there is no *Your Answer* title and the submit button says *Save Edits*:

> [image]