# Attempting to modify my answer produces a new second answer

Tags: bug, edits

Just wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47360071/772868), reconsidered the name and thus edited it again. Effectively, that edit came out as a separate answer which I have deleted.

Clarification dupe flag: The difference to the proposed duplicate is that I never got any message by the system that a new answer was posted. Some years ago it occurred quite often that I was alerted of my own answers. It seems the suggested dupe is rather of this type which I have not observed for, say, a year or more.

Comment: So you clicked save edit, and then another answer was posted? It kind of looks like you just clicked add another answer instead of edit :P Can you include more of the process you used here? Perhaps an environment you were using?

Comment: @Travis: As you can imagine, I only realized this when OP told me so. Adding a new answer involves not only a dialog but also the need to copy the entire answer into the new window. This looks highly unlikely to me. My memory may fail, but I doubt it fails that much. All the relevant things should be visible from history etc.  FF 52.0.2 Ubuntu

Comment: You're not the first to report this on Meta, so it may be a legitimate bug.

Comment: I had this happen once, but I navigated with the browser back and forth buttons, and when it showed me the post,  on saving I had a new answer. Did you navigate? Was there maybe an edit or comment notification which you clicked?

Comment: @rene: I cannot remember such. But I could very well have done such.

Comment: I have also experienced this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38610779/5292302, 1 year ago, unfortunately me neither knows exactly how to reproduce it. Chrome and Windows 10

Comment: I saw this type of behavior in one of the question yesterday, I am not sure whether the person who answered did it knowingly or became victim of this bug. I left comment to merge them if they refer to same solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363610/script-src-not-loading-javascript-for-angular/47363944#comment81680737_47363944).

Comment: I reported this before. It was more or less acknowledged then, but no follow-up. Possible duplicate of [Duplicate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265986/duplicate-answer)

Comment: @GolezTrol: That's related, but the behavior is different. I never got a message that another answer was posted. It was the OP who drew my attention to this.

Comment: The message was just a notification that you may get while you're typing an answer, just so you can check it before posting. It's not an actual popup that you get when posting. I don't know if they still show that notification at all, but I think it's irrelevant for the *actual* bug (duplication), although it may be an indication that the duplicated is posted as soon as you start editing, rather than when you post the edit.

Comment: [something similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290669/849891) happened to me once. there was no alert either.